# Armature does not follow the model

Tags: bones, physics

I have constructed a small pipe. Then I have managed to bend the pipe, with an armature and, I have made it, an active rigid body. The problem is that although the model falls properly on the plane, however its armature stays in its original position.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

[image]

Comment: You could make the armature follow the mesh with some tedious tricks but it looks like you use the armature to bend the mesh, so there will probably be a circular dependency here (a parent can't be the child of its child), but what exactly is your goal here?

Comment: My goal is for the bones, to fall along with the object, through gravity simulation.

Comment: sure, but what for? what is the whole animation for, etc?

Comment: The whole animation is a prototype. I need it in order to create the necessary physics for animating a belt for the quiver, of the sword of Leonidas. I want it to fall along with its armature, on a rock, instead of animating it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated work around and won't work 100% of the time:

-Add a second pipe (or any object), have that pipe copy the location of the first one via the object constraint copy location. Don't render it if needed

-Use the bone constraint in pose mode to copy location of each bone to the second object

-The first pipe is still parented to the armature but now can move via rigid body physics.

Can get you results like this and fiddling more with the constraints should enable better results:
[image]

Weakness of this mode:

-You will have to remove the armature deform modifier of the first object, after the physics simulation is done remove all the constraints and only then be able to use the armature to modify the mesh again. You can also apply the armature modifier.

Another option is to parent the armature to the second object but this will make stuff even more prone to busting and the only advantage is that you don't have to X out the armature modifier.

The problem here is the circular refference as rigs/armatures can't have physics. The only answer that comes to mind is weird constraints usage that won't give you the best results always.

Also please try to include Blender files and which version Blender you are runing when posting questions as that can help massively.

Best of fortunes!